# Pure JS Horizontal Dot Navigation Without External Packages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, navigation, horizontal-scrolling

I'm working with Vue and Laravel and I'm trying to give a scrollable, horizontal container some dots for navigation. I **can't use any jQuery, or external packages or components** - just pure javascript and CSS is what I'm looking for.

I'm displaying a list of divs with textareas and icons that can be selected. Essentially, I want to have something that looks almost exactly like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/darcher/dLmyhgzq/249/ , but with my divs (that I've named message) in this form (pseudocode obviously)

`<div v-for(every 3 message in messages)>
   <navigation-dot></navigation-dot>
 </div>`

..but without using scrollspy if possible (there are no hrefs or links in my divs, so I'd like to try an alternative solution that doesn't involve hrefs if it can be done). In addition, my list includes options to add or remove the divs at runtime, so the navigation dots (and any hrefs/IDs) will have to be updated each time.

I'm using bootstrap, and have tried `<b-carousel>` but it was glitchy and not the solution I'm looking for (as in the demo, I have three items side by side with no page/slide breaks, and I can't find any multi-item `<b-carousel>` examples online).

Does anyone know of any non-jquery solutions to coding this solution? Any guidance would be appreciated as I've been looking for a horizontal navigation implementation for some time. Thank you.